# Aside from grunt, what are the alternative tools or methods of deploying AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I was checking on grunt, but after seeing that it was Node.js, i thought that i might need to download a list of dependencies. My net is slow, so I was trying to find out if there are other good choices out there?

Why are you saying your choice is better? what are the advantages?

Thanks.

**Updated**

There might be an answer out there, please don't vote to close this early. I like a solution that is efficient in terms of resource with respect to my development. Currently, I have no other projects that would use Node.js and its dependencies, so the download might be too much.

Comment: It's possible to create an AngularJs project without using grunt or any other tools : just point on the expected libs manually. (if you're trying to create a project for your own, it may be the simpliest solution)

Comment: If you want to absolutely avoid grunt (or gulp), I do not see any choice for you than reinventing the wheel (minification, css, useref...). Keep in mind that if your build conf is well done you only have to download a max of 100Mo only one time and some updates sometimes.

Comment: I believe its resistance to change. Once you are accustomed to node.js ecosystem, you will find tools like grunt, bower and yeoman very useful and will offset the disadvantage you are facing.